# react-slick without sliding effect

Tags: reactjs, slick.js, react-slick

I'm using this npm component to create a carousel.
https://github.com/akiran/react-slick

This is working great, but I need to find a way to remove the sliding effect.
There is a `slide` Property via the repo's doc but it seems not to work. Did anyone came across this case? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable the sliding effect and have the slides remain in place while they transition, you can accomplish this with the **fade** property. It's shown quite well at this link https://react-slick.neostack.com/docs/example/fade but a simplified example is shown below:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Slider from "react-slick";

class Carousel extends Component {
  render() {
   const settings = {   
     slidesToShow: 1,
     fade: true
   };

  return (
    <div>
      <Slider {...settings}>
        // Carousel data here                
      </Slider>
    </div>
  );
}
```